# Problem with converting a 32 digit hexadecimal number to long

Tags: c#, hex

I tried

```
string inpStr = "800000000000000026FFF40000000000";
long num = long.Parse(inpStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

and get the error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int64". If I use a 16 digit hex, it works fine. How do I get it to work with a 32 digit hex value?

Comment: Does this work? `BigInteger num = BigInteger.Parse(inpStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber)`;

Comment: @Gabe: you mean like I posted 5 minutes ago? ;)

Comment: Mitch: You hadn't posted it when I first loaded the page.

Answer (score 4):

A 32 digit hex number won't fit in a `long` (which is 64 bits, so can hold at most a 16 digit hex value)

In .NET 4.0 you can use BigInteger:

```
const string inpStr = "800000000000000026FFF40000000000";
BigInteger num = 
      BigInteger.Parse(inpStr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your value is too large to fit in a `long`.

Your 32-digit hex number uses *log*<sub>2</sub> 16<sup>32</sup> = 128 bits; a `long` uses just 64 bits.